# Where can I see ocean bioluminescence in coastal California?

Tags: usa, california, beaches, southern-california, coastline

I know that Newport Beach has [truly spectacular bioluminescence](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/travel/2020/04/24/bioluminescent-dolphins-newport-beach-orig-vstan-bdk.cnn/video/playlists/cnn-travel-counterprogramming/). Are there other places on the coast of California where the phenomenon can be seen, particularly north of Newport Beach?

[image: Newport Beach bioluminescence]

Comment: It was spectacular in about April or May but nothing to see right now (at least where I am, on the same coast but in northern Mexico).  So you _might_ be out of luck if you're looking for something now, but I think we get it almost every year at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

San Diego. https://www.pointloma-obmonthly.com/news/story/2020-05-04/the-ocean-blue-bioluminescence-glows-along-sunset-cliffs ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200730032249/https://www.pointloma-obmonthly.com/news/story/2020-05-04/the-ocean-blue-bioluminescence-glows-along-sunset-cliffs)):

> In addition to Sunset Cliffs, the phenomenon has been particularly dramatic at Ocean Beach, the Scripps Pier area of La Jolla, Cardiff-by-the-Sea and off the San Elijo State Beach campgrounds.

La Jolla, San Diego:

[image]

([image source](https://www.instagram.com/p/CAUOHUfDgzN/), author:  [Jesse Bowen](https://www.instagram.com/therealjbowen/))

Also present in [Mission Bay, San Diego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Bay_(San_Diego)): https://www.instagram.com/p/ByL-EkKnDaf/

[image]

([image source](https://www.instagram.com/p/ByL-EkKnDaf/), author:  [Jesse Bowen](https://www.instagram.com/therealjbowen/))

A video, still in San Diego: https://youtu.be/qlTCB_p3slY

More information on https://www.10news.com/lifestyle/exploring-san-diego/tips-on-enjoying-san-diegos-bioluminescence-waves-safely ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200730032631/https://www.10news.com/lifestyle/exploring-san-diego/tips-on-enjoying-san-diegos-bioluminescence-waves-safely)):

> With the [red tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_tide) along San Diego's shore, locals have been flocking to the coast nightly to catch a glimpse of bioluminescent waves.
>
> The waves are created when phytoplankton, called "dinoflagellates," crash in the tide, reacting and causing bioluminescence when jostled

Comment: Note that "red tides" are seasonal (springtime) and are not very predictable as far as timing, duration, or intensity.  If you plan a trip far in advance in hopes of seeing this phenomenon, you'll likely be disappointed.

Comment: @NateEldredge you'll see red

Comment: That is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

I've been on a night time bioluminescence kayak tour in Tomales Bay, a bit more than an hour north of San Francisco.  A couple tour companies run organized tours, or you can just bring your own kayak to the [launch at Nick's Cove](https://goo.gl/maps/XoRNqCyWcHQyckAE7) and paddle around Hog Island and back.  While I thought the experience was very cool, when I went it wasn't nearly as spectacular as the videos and pictures usually show - it was more like some light sparkles for a short moment as your paddle or hand pushes through the water, not long trails of light.  It definitely wasn't something that would be easily noticeable from outside the water.

Comment: I know, I've been there too, that's why I specified "ocean" and "coastal". Probably the northernmost point in California where this happens though!

Answer (score 0):

[San Clemente had strong bioluminescence](https://www.ocregister.com/neon-bioluminescent-waves-fading-after-making-the-ocean-glow-off-southern-california-coast) due to "red waves" in May 2020, but it's gone now and currents are tough to track.